# Kullback Leibler Divergence for Gaussian process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, numerical-methods, machine-learning, information-theory

The Kullback-Leibler divergence between two n - variate normal distribution say $ F_{1} =  N_{n} (0, C_{1}+\sigma^{2}I)$ and  $ F_{2} =  N_{n} (0, C_{2}+\sigma^{2}I)$ is $$ KL(F_{2}: F_{1}) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\text{tr}(C_{2}^{-1}C_{1}) - n - \text{log}{{\text{(det}}(C_{2}^{-1}C_{1}))}\right]$$ Suppose that  following are met:

1. $C_{1}$ is a full matrix with dimension $n * n $  and can be decompose as $UDU'$ where $ U_{n*n}$ orthogonal matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
2. $C_{2}$ is a a best approximation matrix with dimension $m * m $  and can be decompose as $E D E'$ where $ E_{m*n}$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
3. I know that $ C_{1} - C_{2} = U_{(n-m)}L U'_{(n-m)} $ and if  $ || C_{1} - C_{2}||_F< \epsilon $ then I need to find the upper bound for $KL(F_{2}: F_{1})$.

This was how I proceeded and got stuck and will need a good direction to continue. 
First consider $ \text{tr}(C_{1}^{-1}C_{2}) - n $
\begin{align*}
tr(C_{2}^{-1}C_{1}) - n 
&= tr(C_{2}^{-1}(C_{1}-C_{2}))\\ 
&= tr(ED^{-1}E' U_{(n-m)}L U'_{(n-m)})\quad \text{using the property of orthogonality for $E, U $}\\
&= tr(D^{-1}L) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} d_i l_j
tr(C_{2}^{-1}C_{1}) - n \\
&\leq tr(C_{2}^{-1}(C_{1}-C_{2}))\\ 
&\leq ||C_2^{-1}||_{max} \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} d_i l_j \\
&\leq ||C_2^{-1}||_{max} n^{2}\epsilon\\
&\leq \left(\frac{n}{\sigma}\right)^2 \epsilon
\end{align*}

The problem I have is, is the third and fourth line of the equation valid? Once , I know this is correct I will proceed with $ \text{log}{{\text{(det}}(C_{2}^{-1}C_{1}}))$.

Comment: If $m\neq n$ how can $C_1 - C_2$ be well defined? I may be confused about the notation.

Comment: Kindly look at definition 2. Its well defined. I understand your point but think of it as it having the same dimension.